# How to use plugins in Extjs

Tags: extjs4.2

I am finding it very difficult to use 'Ext.ux.TabReorderer' as a plugin in tab panel

```
Ext.define("practical.view.Board",{
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.board',
    plugins: ['Ext.ux.TabReorderer'],
    items:[{
        title: 'Tab 1'
    },{
        title: 'Tab 2'
    }]
});
```

This was throwing an console error saying:

> Cannot read property 'init' of null

Upon further investigation found that there is no folder called 'ux' in my extjs. Also a quick search showed me that there is a file named 'Ext.ux.TabReorderer.js' in  'extjs\docs\output' folder.

This is confusing me, how do I add this plugin to my tab panel ?

**Edit:**

After going through the link provided in the comments by DSF

I added Path in app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux': './app/ux'
    }
});
```

Also changed the tab panel to include

```
Ext.require(['Ext.ux.TabReorderer']);
Ext.define("practical.view.Board",{...
...
```

It is now giving me new errors :

> 1) Uncaught TypeError: Ext.data.JsonP.Ext_ux_TabReorderer is not a
>   function (TabReorderer.js)
>
> 2) Uncaught Error: The following classes are not declared even if
>   their files have been loaded: 'Ext.ux.TabReorderer'. Please check the
>   source code of their corresponding files for possible typos:
>   './app/ux/TabReorderer.js (ext-all-dev.js)

Comment: Take a look on this: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?211867-Using-TabReorderer-as-a-plugin

Comment: Do what error message says: Check if there are any syntax errors in the plugin file. Pay special attention to the correct plugin class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to fix it.

I moved TabReorderer.js from `extjs\docs\output` folder to `extjs\src\ux`.

The reason this didn't work earlier was because I was providing a class name inside the plugins array.

```
plugins: ['Ext.ux.TabReorderer']
```

Where it should have been an **instance of that class**, as shown below

```
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.ux.TabReorderer')]
```

Another way to add plugins would be to use a **ptype**. For example

```
plugins: [{ptype: 'cellediting'}]
```

One can find a list of all the ptypes in [Sencha docs](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.enums.Plugin)

Unfortunately there is no ptype for TabReorderer, so had to stick with Ext.create().

For further reading

http://www.sencha.com/blog/using-plugins-and-mixins-in-your-sencha-apps/

Comment: Could not add another link below further reading as Stackoverflow requires users to have more than 10 reps to post more than 2 links in an answer. So I am pasting the link in comments, I will add more if I find more interesting stuff. http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-plugins

Comment: This was broken for me in 4.2.1 but was working in 4.2.5 so I copied the source code of both BoxReorder and TabReorder to my app and it worked.